# Int object has not a attribute lower - how to resolve

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer

I'm little confused: Below code is working for my friends, but for me it's not.  I've gotten this message:
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'`
This is my code:

```
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Bide1n_tweets.xlsx", error_bad_lines=False)
def tokenization(text):
    text = re.split('\W+', text)
    return text
df['Tweet_tokenized'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: tokenization(x.lower()))
```

This is my dataframe

```
Unnamed: 0  Text
0   0   RT @bennyjohnson:  BOMBSHELL \n\nVeteran &am...
1   1   RT @realDonaldTrump: Finally! Suburban women a...
2   2   RT @MaajidNawaz: BREAKING:\nUS Navy veteran Lt.
```

What should I be doing? Should I put `str()`?

Answer (score 1):

Convert values to strings:

```
df['Tweet_tokenized'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: tokenization(str(x).lower()))
```

Or:

```
df['Tweet_tokenized'] = df['Text'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: tokenization(x.lower()))
```